# Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given. Spring Integration

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-integration, cglib

I'm developing web application supported by Spring Integration. I'm using 1.0.4.RELEASE. I use CGLib proxies. I have a transactional message endpoint. Everything worked correctly, but I experimented a little bit with annotations. I use annotation-config, which works fine. I started from switching my service-activator configuration from xml to annotations, but it failed.

The following configuration worked correctly:

**spring-integration.xml**

```
<channel id="inChannel" />
<channel id="outChannel" />
<service-activator method="myMethod" input-channel="inChannel" ref="myService" output-channel="outChannel" />
```

**MyService.java**

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Transactional
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private MyDao myDao;

   public MyObject myMethod(String message) throws Exception {
      ...
   }

}
```

Trying to achieve exactly the same functionality using annotations (having in mind that I use CGLIB, so I do not need interface, but default constructor) I

- removed service-activator from my .xml
- changed MyService:

**Changed MyService.java**

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Transactional
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private MyDao myDao;

   public MyService () {
   }

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="inChannel", outputChannel="outChannel")
   public MyObject myMethod(String message) throws Exception {
      ...
   }

}
```

I get the following error:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given**

I've seen many threads describing the following error [article](http://noobjuggler.blogspot.com/2011/10/javalangillegalargumentexception.html), but the problem was about custom classes. My problem regards Spring class.

```
Error creating bean with name 'myService'
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

What's wrong? Why Spring tries to create proxy for spring class but not only for MyService? Is my class somehow wrapped? I don't understand what's happening. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking off the `@Autowired` Tag. That looks for a constructor or setter method in order to populate that field. Considering you have neither of those, that might be the problem. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

OR you can make myDao package-protected or public (so that Spring can actually autowire it)

for instance:

```
@Autowired
myDao
```